# ngx-datatable highlight column

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable (https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/ ). Is there a way to add a column highlight? I have been trying to find a way to do this with `[cellClass]` and `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` and `[ngClass]` and a million different ways and I can't get it to function correctly. Has anyone been able to add a column highlight when someone mouses over a `data-body-cell`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you got the answer for this?